# Display custom domain in search results rather than wordpress.com subdomain

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain, wordpress.com

How to show a custom domain URL instead of domain's URL assigned by wordpress.com in the Google search results?

For example, if I have free subdomain like `http://example.wordpress.com`, how can I show `http://www.example.com` instead of `http://example.wordpress.com` in the google search results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google always shows the actual URL for your site and never uses alternate domains.

If you want to show your custom domain in the Google Search results, you have to use that domain for your site.   Wordpress.com has instructions for doing so [here](https://wordpress.com/support/domains/).  The basic steps are:

- Register the domain
- Add the domain to your wordpress.com account
- Point or transfer the domain to wordpress.com for hosting
- Set the domain as the primary domain for your account

That last step requires that you pay for wordpress.com hosting.  There doesn't appear to be a way to use a free wordpress.com account with a custom domain set as the primary.

Comment: Thank you sir for your kindly help.